# If $ x \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Z}, n \in \Bbb{N} $ for $ y = \sqrt[n]{x} $ then $ y \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Z} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is this statement true ?

If:
$$ y = \sqrt[n]{x} $$
$$ x \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Z}, n \in \Bbb{N} $$
Then:
$$ y \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Z} $$

Comment: To denote important sets like real, rational, integer, and complex numbers use `\Bbb{}` (blackboard bold)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By contraposition:
$$
y\in\Bbb Z \Rightarrow x=y^n \in \Bbb Z.
$$